# Apportionment models, niche theory, neutral theory

Tags: ecology, book-recommendation, biodiversity, community-ecology

I am trying to understand the relation between [apportionment models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niche_apportionment_models), niche theory, and [neutral theory of biodiversity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_neutral_theory_of_biodiversity). Wikipedia seems to suggest that the first two are the same thing, whereas the last one is controversial

> The theory has sparked controversy, and some authors consider it a more complex version
> of other null models that fit the data better.

This impression is further enforced by the fact that the Hubbell's original books seems to be almost the only source of information about this model.

On the other hand, [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6329381/) suggests that *modern niche theory* is a synthesis of the apportionment models and the neutral theory

> Niche-based theories have emphasized the role of competition for resources, while neutral theory has
> highlighted the role of stochastic effects, and several works have investigated the interplay
> between stochasticity and competition.Many of these theoretical insights have been synthesized
> in what is commonly referred to as contemporary niche theory. Contemporary niche theory highlights
> the role played by equalizing mechanisms, processes that decrease fitness differences between
> organisms, and stabilizing mechanisms, processes that decrease competition for resources. These basic
> organizational schema have been successfully applied to understand community structure in a wide range
> of settings.

I am looking for guidance in this theory landscape, comments on what is mainstream and what is not, and suggestions for deeper reading (math is welcome).

**Remark:**  It is understood here *that neutral theory of biodiversity* is not the same as the *neutral theory* in population genetics (although the latter might have inspired the former).

**Additional references:**

- [The unified neutral theory of biodiversity and biogeography at age 10](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0169534711000942) - Article by Hubbell, outlining successes of the neutral theory.
- [Conceptual synthesis in community ecology](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20565040/) - this articles draws extensive parallels between the community ecology and population genetics, but light on math.
- [The transition between the niche and neutral regimes in ecology](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4246938/) - a physics-minded model, demonstrating a transition between *niche* and *neutral* behavior depending on the population size and environmental factors.

Comment: I think I would start with Letten et al.  https://doi.org/10.1002/ecm.1242  . BTW I wouldn't say "modern" niche theory, "contemporary niche theory" appears to be the standard terminology ...  I wouldn't say Hubbell's book is the only source - there are **lots** of research papers ...